# Javascript & Cookies : count visits for all pages

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies

For the first time i write cookies (on a wordpress site), i use a script which counts the visits to make an action on the 4th page seen.

It works but it just count the number of visits for each pages and i want it to count the number of visits of the totality of pages.

i hope my explanation is clear, thanks.

```
function scookie(name,value,days)
    {
        var expire=new Date();
        var days = 365;
        expire.setDate(expire.getDate()+days);
        expire = expire.toGMTString();
        document.cookie=name+'='+escape(value)+';   expires=' + expire;
        return true;
    }
function gcookie(name)
    {
        if(document.cookie.length>0)
        {
            start=document.cookie.indexOf(name+"=");
            pos = start+name.length+1;
            if(start!=0) {
                start=document.cookie.indexOf("; "+name+"=");
                pos = start+name.length+3;
            } if(start!=-1) {
                start=pos;
                end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",start);
                if(end==-1)
                {
                    end=document.cookie.length;
                }
                return unescape(document.cookie.substring(start,end));
            }
        }
        return '';
    }

if( gcookie('nb_visits')=='' || gcookie('nb_visits')=='' )
    {
        nb_visits=1;
    }
 else
    {
        nb_visits = Number(gcookie('nb_visits'))+1;
    }
scookie('nb_visits',nb_visits,100);

if (nb_visits == '4')
    {
        console.log('This is your 4th Visit');
    }
```

Comment: What kind of site do you have in place ? `php` with Header & footer etc, some more information would be nice

Comment: Yes, it's on an existing wordpress site

Comment: is "wordpress" an sufficient information to have a good technical aspect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found the (very simple) solution few time after.

Here it is "the solution" if someone is looking to do the same thing.

Just add the path (here "/" for root of the site) at the end of the scookie function :

```
function scookie(name,value,days,path)
    {
        var expire=new Date();
        var days = 365;
        expire.setDate(expire.getDate()+days);
        expire = expire.toGMTString();
        document.cookie=name+'='+escape(value)+';   expires=' + expire + ";path=/" ;
        return true;
    }
```